# Time based collection and events

Tags: c#, .net, events, collections

I would like to bulk insert a collection content every minute to a sql server using bulk insert.

I m using a ConcurrentBag to store requests in the memory.

What s the best practice to do this? or How can this be done?

I understand that I have to use events, should i wrap the collection within another class and implement expiration?

How do i use events for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the requirement is not general purpose enough and the code to achieve this is small, so personally I think it's not necessary to create a separate class. At least if the containing class is not already overly long and complex. However this is more or less a matter of taste.

To achieve what you want, it should be enough to use the `Timer` class and on every timer tick enumerate the collection inserting the items in the database and removing them from the collection at the same time. GetEnumerator on `ConcurrentBag` works on a Snapshot of the data, so it's safe to remove the items while enumerating.

Comment: Why would i enumerate to remove? there is already a TryTake method which removes from bag. as far as the timer, nutshell book claims it causes memory leaks.

Comment: What timer are you using? There are a lot of different timer classes in the framework. I'm not sure what he means by memory leaks. Maybe he is referring to the event, which will hold on to a reference of the object containing your event handler... But this is a general thing you have to look at when using events. Just unregister the event when it's no longer used.

Comment: As to TryTake of course it works the same. I just like using foreach ;-)

Comment: I looked up the page in the nutshell book. It only tells you to take care to call Dispose() on the timer after you don't use it anymore, so that all resources are freed.